# No traffice on tun0 with wireshark/tcpdump

Tags: openvpn, wireshark, sniffing

I'm connected to a testing lab via openvpn and it's obviously created a tun interface. As part of this assessment I am supposed to analyze traffic on that network, however when I open wireshark there is no traffic on that interface. At all, none, nada... zip. Can ping every machine, scan with nmap etc but no packets to see.

I have checked [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63663/no-packets-showing-up-in-wireshark-despite-client-server-communication) post but I am definitely choosing the correct interface. For the record there is lots of local network traffic on my wlan interface e.g. router, chromecast etc, but nothing that reflects any kind of connection to the testing lab.

Comment: "As part of this assessment I am supposed to analyze traffic on that network" You mean from your machine to and from that network, or on that network in general? The latter is not going to work, as only traffic from and to your machine is going to show up on your machine. Other than that, systematically debug it: Start `openvpn` in a terminal, double check output for the tun interface. Use `ip route get 1.2.3.4` where 1.2.3.4 is in the tunneled network to see it goes through tun0. Start a `ping 1.2.3.4`, check with `sudo tcpdump -n -i tun0` to see if  your wireshark is faulty. Etc.

Comment: To and from machine. Ok I'll check tcpdump with those flags.

Comment: Ok that's super weird. It's working now, for the entire network. The only thing I did was `ip route get <ip addr>`

Comment: The `ip route get` is probably unrelated, my money is on that you forgot some detail the last time you tried, and now you did it properly.

Comment: Yeh the only thing I can think of is I may or may not have restarted the openvpn connection. Haven't touched anything else and I don't control the labs so who knows really....